# My computer crashes during a System Rating?

Tags: windows-7, crash

I attempted at performing a system rating on my Windows 7 computer - I built it today.. I can't seem to find a explanation anywhere;

It happened when it was coming to an end/during the "Pxxxx CPU Performance" test (it had a word infront of CPU, starting with P, can't remember it now..) is there somewhere I can check what has happened?

The computer just reboots itself, no error messages.. I don't understand!

**Problem fixed, solution**:

Go into Advanced System Settings, click Settings button under Startup and Recovery, uncheck Automatically restart.

Comment: look in the System Event Logs

Comment: what does "crash" mean? BSOD? Please add any error messages

Comment: No error messages, just crashes (computer reboots), and no BSOD.

Comment: Ah, you probably have it set to auto reboot on error (which for some bizarre reason is the default for Win7). Go into `Advanced System Settings`, click `Settings` button under `Startup and Recovery`, uncheck `Automatically restart`. Then try again and you should see the BSOD

Comment: It should also be in the event log as well

Comment: Where do I check in the event log? Never had to use it, since my other computers never have had problems.

Comment: Open `Control Panel` and search for `event` - should be an option for `View event logs`. Open the `Windows Logs` node and check in the `Application` and `System` logs for any errors (red exclamation icon)

Comment: Seems to not restart now, that I unchecked "Automatically restart"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have it set to auto reboot on error (which for some bizarre reason is the default for Win7).

Go into `Advanced System Settings`, click `Settings` button under `Startup and Recovery`, uncheck `Automatically restart`.

Then try again

Answer (score 0):

Before any new video card is set up you first have to go into your bios and make sure to move your primary video card setting to PCI-E if your using Exspress.  Next reboot os... This all happens before you install drivers from the manufacturer only... Here's the hard part... You need to start over fresh in order for it to work. System restore or delteing drivers will not do it at this point.